# AWT-EventQueue-2 thread

Tags: java, java-web-start

in my **`JNLP app`**, I see 3 threads that look related to **Swing / AWT:**

```
AWT-EventQueue-0
AWT-EventQueue-1
AWT-EventQueue-2
```

How can I find out what each thread represents / does?

Comment: there is no exception, I am seeing these threads live and I want to know what they do.

Comment: You could monitor the app with VisualVM (using the Sampler feature) and inspect the stack traces.

Comment: Looks like normal event dispatch threads in a situation when you have a couple of nested modal windows.